# Issue signing into Firebase using Auth0 token / Open ID Connect

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, auth0

**Issue:**

I'm attempting to login with Auth0 and Firebase Authentication (so I can access my database).

I'm able to click a button to redirect to Auth0 (from my Angular app), then login and be redirected back to my Angular app.

Then I have a listener to grab the raw token from Auth0.

Then, I use the method signInWithCredential (from firebase/auth) to attempt to login with that token and provider details (see code example below).

I have wired up Auth0 to Firebase Open ID Connect (see screenshot below) and use the provider to link this: OAuthProvider('oidc.test').

**Outcome I'd like:**

To sign in to Firebase Authentication using Auth0 token e.g. Open ID Connect.

**The issue is I get this error from signInWithCredential method:**

"OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED : The identity provider configuration is not found."

**Tech Stack:**

Angular version 15, Firebase, Typescript, Firebase Authentication Open ID Connect, Auth0 (third party).

** Angular component: code attempt example:**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Auth0 listener - get token
    this.authService.idTokenClaims$.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.token = data.__raw;
      }
    })

    // Auth0 listener - get user
    this.authService.user$.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.login();
        }, 1500);
      }
    })
  }

  logOut(): void {
    this.authService.logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: document.location.origin } })
  }

  sso(): void {
    this.authService.loginWithRedirect();
  }

  login(): void {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const provider = new OAuthProvider('oidc.test');
    const credential = provider.credential({
      idToken: this.token,
    });

    signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

**Error (console request error):**

[image]

**Firebase config:**

[image]

**Instructions I've been following for Firebase (scroll to the bottom of the page once link clicked):**

Handle the sign-in flow manually from this firebase link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/openid-connect#web-version-9

Instructions I've been following for Auth0:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular/interactive

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue?